# Dot Matrix Printer Printing Landscape Only When Printing from PDF in Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, printing, crystal-reports

In my asp.net application First I convert my crystal report to pdf and then print it. Everything is working fine. But when I am trying to print it from Dot Matrix Printer It's printing Landscape only instead of Portrait.

I tried to set Portrait from Printer Properties but nothing worked.

Any Help Will be Appreciated....

Comment: have you tried to modify the settings of the printer instead of report's?

Comment: Yes I did... But nothing worked